# Error en ViewChild Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Saludos estoy tratando de realizar una llamada de un metodo entre componentes en Angular,para esto estoy utilizando el decorador ViewChild, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { PacienteComponent } from '../atencion/paciente/paciente.component';
export class AtencionComponent implements OnInit {


@ViewChild(PacienteComponent,{static: true}) pacientePrueba: PacienteComponent;

  pruebaSelect(){  
    
    this.pacientePrueba.funcionPrueba();
  }    

}
```

"funcionPrueba()" es una funcion que está definida en el componente de "PacienteComponent", pero al hacerlo la variable "pacientePrueba" me sale undefined, no sé que estoy haciendo mal espero me ayuden

Comment: puedes agregar tu html y que es lo que haces con esa referencia en el metodo

Comment: cuando o donde llamas la función `pruebaSelect`? Prueba con `@ViewChild(PacienteComponent,{static: false})`

Answer (score 0):

A partir de la versión 9 la forma de declarlo es diferente:

```
 @ViewChild(PacienteComponent,{static: true})
```

[referencia](https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration)

Si `PacienteComponent` no es un hijo de `AtencionComponent` puedes llamar el método creando una instancia de la clase `PacienteComponent`:

```
pacienteComponent = new PacienteComponent();
pacienteComponent.funcionPrueba();
```

Comment: Añadiendo esto me quedo asi:
@ViewChild(PacienteComponent,{static: true}) pacientePrueba: PacienteComponent; pero aun asi me sigue saliendo undefined voy aa actualizar con esto

Comment: Y PacienteCompoment está en el html de AtencionComponent?

Comment: lo que quiero es acceder a una funcion que está en el PacienteComponent, la funcion es "funcionPrueba()"

Answer (score 0):

En el HTML de AtencionComponent debe existir una etiqueta HTML , de tal manera que en el AtencionComponent como en el atencion-component.html existan las referencias de PacienteComponent

Toda referencia de un componente ViewChield debe existir en el HTML del ViewChield que lo instancia. (No siempre, pero si es importante que lo sepas cuándo estás iniciando)

En caso de que no sea necesaria una referencia en el HTML, se debe colocar *static: false* y hacer un new PacienteComponent ()

Aunque según la necesidad que planteas, seguramente estás usando una lógica compleja, seguramente debe haber otra opción para resolver lo que quieres hacer. Pues generalmente, no sé debe acceder a una función que está en un componente si no siquiera se va a interactuar con el componente.
Saludos!